# How to call VBA macro from AHK in Excel when editing a cell?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, autohotkey

I have an autohotkey script which calls an Excel macro. Basically I have a universal shortcut to add a task to my custom GTD application in Excel

My AHK code is as follows:

```
RunMSExcelMacro(MacroName, args) {      ; for AHK_L
    oExcel := ComObjActive("Excel.Application")
   ; oExcel.Workbooks("gtd_active.xlsm").Run(MacroName,args)
    oExcel.Run("'gtd_active.xlsm'!"+MacroName,args)
    ;oExcel.Run(MacroName,args)
}

#Space::
InputBox, newTask, Add New Task to GTD, What is the new task?, , 380, 130 
if (newtask = "" or ErrorLevel){ ;if blank or "cancel" pressed (ErrorLevel = 1) don't do anything
return
}
else
{RunMSExcelMacro("addFromAHK", newTask) 
}
return
```

The method in Excel is as follows:

```
'this script allows AutoHotKey to add items to the GTD list
'without having to even access Excel - wtf hax :-)
Sub addFromAHK(ByRef newTask As String)

    Dim myCell As Range
    'I don't like hardcoding this but I cant be bothered to
    'make this reference the constant right now
    Set myCell = MasterList.Range("C50000").End(xlUp)

    'ugh such a hack. No easy way to get last cell without defiltering
    Do Until IsEmpty(myCell) = True
        Set myCell = myCell.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

    'save the task
    myCell.value = newTask


End Sub
```

Unfortunately, if I am currently editing a cell in Excel I cannot call a macro, so the global shortcut fails. Note this fails before I am able to call the Excel macro.

Is there an easy way to change the AHK code to basically "exit cell editing" if I'm doing that? I don't want to write a huge amount of code to do this but I'm really not sure the best approach here.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "editing a cell"? Also, what Excel version are you using?

Comment: @MCL when I am actually editing a cell. IE the cursor is in it. Excel 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time I made use of AHK_L's `try/catch` (yay!). Check out this code example:

```
RunMyMacro() {
    oExcel := ComObjActive("Excel.Application")
    try {
        oExcel.Run("'MyFile.xlsm'!TestSub")
    } catch e {
        ControlSend, , {Enter}, ahk_class XLMAIN
        Sleep, 200
        oExcel.Run("'MyFile.xlsm'!TestSub")
    }
}
```

It's pretty basic, so you'll have to do the fine tuning yourself.
If there's an error calling the macro, we outright assume that that's because we are editing a cell. If you are rather meticulous, you could check the exception's message (`e.Message`) for an error code. On my machine the message was *`0x80010001 Some German BlaBla`*.
To exit cell editing, we simply send <kbd>Enter</kbd> to the Excel Window. If there's multiple Excel Windows, you have to restrict the window title like `MyFile.xlsm ahk_class XLMAIN`.
After the `Sleep` (you may want to play around with the exact timeout), we call our macro again.

Comment: AHK_L has try/catch?  I love it more every day. I'll have to try this sometime today (it's on my work machine) but I suspect this will work.

Comment: [It does indeed](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/commands/Try.htm)! Although I don't get why they left out my beloved `finally`.